# Select 1 of 2 similar records where does not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table called 'Requests' which stores requests for holidays. I want to try extract certain records from the table (joined with others) with the parameter of the clocknumber. But, if there are two records with the same HolidayID and the last (top 1 desc) is of a certain value - we dont include that in the select!

Request Table [shortened down version of it];

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY1Gk.png

The stored procedure im using is passed a parameter for the username and joins three other tables,

- a 'Holidays' table (Stores information on the holiday from, to etc)
- a 'Users' table (contains usernames etc)
- a 'RequestType' table (contains the types of requests)

From the image of the table, If you imagine all of those requests belong to the same user, I would want to extract only the records with a requesttype of 1. (the requesttype 1 is holiday request and 2 is holiday cancel). But, if there is a second record with the same holidayID and a requesttype of 2, it does not include that.

So running the query, I would want to only get records with the ID 1 and 2, because the last 2 have the same Holiday ID, and the last of the 2 is with a requesttype to cancel the holiday.

Here is my attempted query;

```
SELECT Holidays.ID, EmployeeClockNumber, Employees.Name AS EmployeeName, HolidayStart, HolidayEnd, HalfDay, AMPM
FROM Holidays
INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.ClockNumber = Holidays.EmployeeClockNumber
INNER JOIN Requests ON Requests.HolidayID = Holidays.ID
WHERE EmployeeClockNumber = @ClockNo 
AND Requests.Accepted = 1
AND RequestTypeID = (SELECT TOP 1 Requests.ID 
                    FROM Requests 
                    INNER JOIN Holidays ON Holidays.ID = Requests.HolidayID
                    WHERE Requests.RequestTypeID = (SELECT ID FROM RequestType WHERE RequestType = 'Holiday Request') 
                    AND Holidays.EmployeeClockNumber = @ClockNo
                    ORDER BY Requests.ID DESC)
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you

edit: ive got it working myself!

```
SELECT Holidays.ID, Holidays.EmployeeClockNumber, Employees.Name AS EmployeeName, Holidays.HolidayStart, Holidays.HolidayEnd, Holidays.HalfDay, Holidays.AMPM
FROM Requests 
INNER JOIN Holidays ON Holidays.ID = Requests.HolidayID
INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.ClockNumber = Holidays.EmployeeClockNumber
WHERE Holidays.EmployeeClockNumber = @ClockNo
AND Requests.Accepted = 1
AND Requests.HolidayID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 HolidayID
                                FROM Requests AS R1
                                WHERE R1.RequestTypeID <> (SELECT ID FROM RequestType WHERE RequestType = 'Holiday Request')
                                AND R1.HolidayID = Requests.HolidayID 
                                ORDER BY R1.ID DESC)
```

Comment: I was going to steer you that way. But you probably don't need the `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a partition on the select and then filter on that.

So something like

```
DECLARE @mtable TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,RequestTypeId INT
    ,HolidayId INT
    ,Accepted NVARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT @mtable VALUES (1,1,1,'True')
INSERT @mtable VALUES (2,1,2,'True')
INSERT @mtable VALUES (3,1,3,'True')
INSERT @mtable VALUES (4,2,3,'True')


SELECT * FROM (
SELECT MAX(RequestTypeId) OVER (PARTITION BY HolidayID) AS MaxType
,Id
FROM @mtable
) q 
WHERE q.MaxType <> 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you've misunderstood the question!

Comment: Yes it will. I have updated my example to be self contained. It will return Ids 1 and 2 as I believe you need.

Comment: Also, my solution is way more efficient than doing a select in the WHERE clause.

Comment: okay jorge, I think I've solved it myself but im a bit of a novice with SQL and have not touched partitions etc. I'd love if you could explain your answer more? I also love the sound of efficiency ! my code is in the original question!

Comment: OVER PARTITION is just a way of doing groupings on certain windows of rows of the result. So, instead of doing a MAX over the whole result set you restrict it to a subset of the results, in our case we are only interested in grouping all the records with the same HolidayId, to look for the groups that have the MAX typeId of a certain value.

Comment: @ jorgesalvador i just gave a hint to think. It can be done using Left join as well.

Comment: Well you said my solution wouldn't work, when it's not true. That's not a hint to think, that's a hint to think wrong! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE requestTypeID  = 1
AND holidayID not in (SELECT HolidayID from TAB WHERE requestTypeID  = 2)
```

Comment: Sort of your doing, gave me inspiration for my answer (it works) see the question